# Python If statement - IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Whats wrong with my If statement?

```
 if (current_value_address == current_value['address'] and
     current_input['xy'] >= current_required_value and 
     current_xy_amount >= MIN_AMO and
     AFFL_COME > 1):

 getaf_id = db.cursor()
```

Error:

```
getaf_id = db.cursor()
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If i remove the If statement it works.

Comment: Because there is no code indented within the `if` block. The error is pretty explicit that it expects something to be indented following your `if` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to indent that last part:

```
 if (current_value_address == current_value['address'] and
 current_input['xy'] >= current_required_value and 
 current_xy_amount >= MIN_AMO and
 AFFL_COME > 1):

     getaf_id = db.cursor().  #indent this line!
```